# Unable to access `Google Endpoints API` with firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

Sorry I don't know If I should ask the question here. I used the `echo` sample project and 
deploy it to `google cloud endpoints`, and I want to configure it with `firebase auth` instead of `api key`.  the following is the `openapi.yaml`

```
paths:
  "/echo":
  post:
    description: "Echo back a given message."
    operationId: "echo"
    produces:
      - "application/json"
    responses:
      200:
        description: "Echo"
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
    parameters:
      - description: "Message to echo"
        in: body
        name: message
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
    security:
      - firebase: []
```

And when I deploy it and access with

```
curl -d '{"message":"hello world"}' -H "content-
type:application/json""http://[IPADDRESS]:80/echo"
```

I get the error message.

```
 "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without 
 established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer 
 identity to call this API.",
```

And if I add the api key.

```
curl -d '{"message":"hello world"}' -H "content-type:application/json""http://35.194.225.89:80/echo?api_key=[API_KEY]"
```

I can get the correct result.

I am not sure how to configure the `openapi.yaml`, please help. thank you very much.

Comment: I figured it out, the configuration is ok, I should redeploy the back end api implementation.